# Webview display .gif at center

Tags: android, webview, gif

I am displaying a .gif in webview. it works!. but it is displaying at left side. I need to display at center.

```
  View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listviewfooter, null, false);
    webviewLoadmore = (WebView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.webviewLoadmore);
    webviewLoadmore.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/load_icon.gif");
```

afterthat I am adding it in Listview Footer.

```
clubListView.addFooterView(webviewLoadmore);
```

my xml layout

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webviewLoadmore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="none" 
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
    >
</WebView>
```

Comment: try  android:gravity="center"

Comment: this is not property of webview

Comment: ohh sorry i mean in layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the Gif in an HTML file and code it like the image will be displayed at the center of webpage (using css obviously). Then load the html page in WebView.

For more details please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257998/1230782)

Comment: Place the html in assets and load it using loadUrl(), Just like you did for gif.

Comment: it is displaying me hello word. but not gif image.

Comment: Man, you just copy pasted that code. Change the html body to show your image. It must be something like, <img src="your gif path"></img>

Comment: <html>
<head>
  <img src="~/android_asset/load_icon.gif"></img>
 </head>
<body>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: it is not displaying image. just show a icon not gif image

Comment: now displaying the image but not center.   <img align="center" src="file:///android_asset/load_icon.gif"></img>

Comment: sorry. not working <html>
<head>
  <img align="middle" src="file:///android_asset/load_icon.gif"></img>
 </head>
<body>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: <center><img align="middle" src="file:///android_asset/load_icon.gif"></img></center> Working for me

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I'm not really good at HTML though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.gif_image);
web.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

OR:

```
public void loadImage(){
   Bitmap BitmapOfMyImage=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                       .getAbsolutePath()+"yourFolder/myImageName.jpg");  

   mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorgeDirectory()  
                               .getAbsolutePath()
                                +"yourFolder/","<html><center>
                                <img src=\"myImageName.jpg\" vspace="
                                +(currentHeight/2-(BitmapOfMyImage.getHeight()/2))+">
                                 </html>","text/html","utf-8","");
 //This loads the image at the center of thee screen                    
}
```