# Show html page in center of WebView

Tags: android, webview

How can I show a webPage in center of webView(match parent width and  height) if webpage's height is less than screen's height? The content I am rendering on webView is comming from epub Files.

For example if screen's height is 1000px and web page's height is 600px.Then it the content should take padding 200px from bottom and top.

Thanx in advance..

Comment: can you provide more info ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set WebView Content in Center?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257442/how-to-set-webview-content-in-center)

Comment: No its not duplicate.Because I am not rendering my own content.

Comment: Most ePub readers apply their own styling in order to have some control over how the content is presented. This is necessary for a paged layout (most readers utilize CSS columns. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts) as well as situations like yours. CSS columns are tricky to get right -- they tend to clip images across two pages. An ePub reader is a tricky thing to get right -- I don't suggest rolling your own.